# "Extract" the magento code, so only a certain part of the site is shown on my C# application

Tags: c#, php, html, visual-studio-2010, magento

Basically what I'm trying to do is integrate a Magento shop with an C# application. The point is, I dont wan't the full magento page to appear, I only want the products to appear in my application and not the full page with the full menus. So my question here is: is there any way, I can "extract" somehow the magento code, so only a certain part of the site is showed on my C# application?

Thanks in advance!
P.S: Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: If you're pulling html from your own site why not just create a new template? If you're pulling information from anyone elses site you may just be stuck with parsing the full page. You could also try something like http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/web_services/using_soap_api_in_c_sharp

Comment: Yes I'm pulling it from myown site, can you tell me more about this new template your talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically draw up a page that displays the products in the way that you want, and load that page rather than the homepage or whatever page you're loading. Like a mobile theme basically. I'm not too familiar with the administrative end so I'm not sure how those are enabled or set, but that's pretty much all you're trying to do.